# Who or whom ? Problem

Tags: sentence-construction

> This is the man **who/whom** i was talking to.

Which should be used in above example and why?
Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

You might find that in everyday English the difference between "who" and "whom" in various contexts has disappeared and speakers prefer "who" over "whom". However, in tests and formal (purely grammatical) English the difference is this ([*Tips and Tricks*](http://linguistech.ca/Tips+and+Tricks+-+Who+vs.+Whom)):

- **Who** is the subject of a verb *(i.e. the one doing the action)*.
- **Whom** is the object of a verb *(i.e. the one being acted upon)*.

In your context, "*I*" is acting upon "*this man*" who is the object of the verb "*to talk*". Thus we get that we need to use "**whom**":

- I was talking to this man (him);
- Who (I) was talking to him?
- Whom (Him) was I talking to?
- Who (He) was this man I was talking to?
- I was talking to this man whom (Him) I didn't know.

Comment: And in this particular sentence, the best option is actually to delete the word altogether!

Comment: Yeh, that would create a reduced clause: "**This is the man I was talking to.**"